# Debugger Not working in IE 10

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In Microsoft Customer relationship management 2011 , debugger in Java Script not working . It giving error that debugger is already attached . Is it a problem Of IE 10 ?

Comment: It is probably an issue with the browser. Does it give that error when F12 is pressed? Have you tried another browser like Chrome?

Comment: It is giving me error when I load java script file for crud operations  on On Save of account . When I tried to save it asks me for debugging , if I say yes, it gives me error debugger is already attached .

Comment: Not even that case but all the times after i installed IE 10 , same error I am facing . I am now unable to attach debugger .

Answer (score 1):

See [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/560579/inplusIE10plus-plusAttachingplustheplusScriptplusd) on Code Project.

Solution 2 states that this error can be caused by trying to have both the Visual Studio debugger and the JavaScript debugger in IE attached at the same time.
Are you trying to use both debuggers at the same time?

Comment: I removed debugger from java script , still the error is there . What should I do?